# UrlRewriteFilter matching multiple rules?

Tags: java, url-rewriting

I have a rule which works just fine:

```
<rule>
    <from>^/(about|account|admin|cpanel)(\?.*)?$</from>
    <to last="true">/faces/pages/$1/$1.xhtml$2</to>
</rule>
```

When I add the following rule *after* the above, I get a `javax.servlet.ServletException: PWC1232: Exceeded maximum depth for nested request dispatches: 20` exception when loading a page that matches the first rule.

```
<rule>
    <from>^/([^\?]+?)/([^\?]+?)(\?.*)?$</from>
    <to last="true">/faces/pages/$1/$2.xhtml$3</to>
</rule>
```

According to the [documentation](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.1/index.html), once the first rule is matched, no more rules should be processed because I specified `last="true"`. Any idea what I might be missing here?

Comment: Damn you stackoverflow and your arbitrary rules. I could not post the above as an answer, at least not for another few hours, because I'm not elite enough.

Comment: Nice work Steve Taylor. Can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about this one. I usually keep things up to date. And yes, I do accept answers to questions that are answered satisfactorily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In web.xml, I changed this (which is shown in the UrlRewriteFilter documentation)

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

to this

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and it started behaving properly. That's weird, but it works.

It seems that the price of not reinventing the wheel is spending 95% of dev time dealing with 3rd pary bugs. (GlassFish being the major offender.)